# Upload photo to website, let it process, and download

Tags: python, file-upload, adobe

I am trying to (with minimal python knowledge) build a simple program that can upload a file to https://new.express.adobe.com/tools/remove-background let it process, and download the result. I've had chatGPT write some basic code for me but I can't get the upload portion working. I'm not sure if the issue is that I do not have the correct selector for the upload button or if there is some other issue standing in the way. Here is the full code I'm working with currently.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

chromedriver_path = r"***"
service = Service(chromedriver_path)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)

url = "https://new.express.adobe.com/tools/remove-background"
driver.get(url)

# Wait for the file input to be present
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "file-input"))
)

# Send the file path directly to the input element
file_input = driver.find_element(By.ID, "file-input")
file_path = r"***"
file_input.send_keys(file_path)

# Wait for the download button to appear
download_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "sp-button[data-export-option-id='downloadExportOption']"))
)
download_button.click()

# Wait for and click the sign-in button
sign_in_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "sp-link.modal-sign-in-link"))
)
sign_in_button.click()

# Enter email and continue
email_input = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "EmailPage-EmailField"))
)
email_input.send_keys("***")
continue_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(), 'Continue')]")
continue_button.click()

# Enter password and continue
password_input = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "PasswordPage-PasswordField"))
)
password_input.send_keys("***")
continue_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(), 'Continue')]")
continue_button.click()

# Wait for the save file dialog to open
time.sleep(5)  # Adjust this delay as needed for the dialog to fully appear

# Simulate pressing 'Enter' to confirm the save action
pyautogui.press('enter')

driver.quit()
```

I have tried targeting a clickable element like dropzone-background and I've tried going directly to the file upload, as in the code I linked above. The result was the window opening, not being able to find or interact with the element, and then closing.